# Reverse list elements at even positions

Tags: ocaml

I know already know how to reverse a list "manually-coded":

```
let rev_list l =
  let rec rev_acc acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | hd::tl -> rev_acc (hd::acc) tl
  in 
  rev_acc [] l
```

And now i try to reverse only those elements that are at even positions, thats mean that for input:

`Function([0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7])`

return is:

`[6;1;4;3;2;5;0;7]`

How can i do this if we assume that we count elements from 0?

Comment: I hope all these questions are not home work for you. If it is, please tell me and I will answer your questions in a hint way, not a direct way. I know it is a bit hard to learn ocaml at the beginning, and I would like to help you in a more proper way.

Comment: direct way is a good way for me to learn. I knew the solution to solve this, i knew that I must have two separate lists. But what i didnt know is how to code this. And on your examples i can look and learn on good piece of code. To thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(* integrate [x1;x2;x3] [y1;y2;y3] = [x1;y1;x2;y2;x3;y3] *)
let integrate l1 l2 = 
  let rec integrt acc = function
    | [], [] -> List.rev acc
    | hd::tl,[] | [], hd::tl -> integrt (hd::acc) (tl,[])
    | hd1::tl1, hd2::tl2 -> integrt (hd2::hd1::acc) (tl1,tl2)
  in 
  integrt [] (l1,l2)

let rev_list_even_pos l=
  let rec rev r_acc acc i = function
    | [] -> integrate r_acc (List.rev acc)
    | hd::tl ->
      if i mod 2 = 0 then rev (hd::r_acc) acc (i+1) tl
      else rev r_acc (hd::acc) (i+1) tl
  in 
  rev [] [] 0 l
```

The trick is to use two separate lists: one stores the reversed elements, the other store elements in original order.